# Server stopped working when I try to a2ensite an ssl.conf file

Tags: http, ssl, https, apache2.4, debian-stretch

I'm currently trying to create a page with `apache2` on a Debian stretch to host an app but when I `a2ensite` the HTTP version it just doesn't work, and when I enable the `ssl` one the entire server stops working, even the pages not related to that one page. Both conf files are fine, I'm stuck, any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT: Logs show this, at 09:06:37 I a2ensite, and stops working, at 09:07:01 I a2dissite and it works again:

```
[Fri Jul 13 09:06:37.059026 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20067] AH00171: 
Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Fri Jul 13 09:06:37.245485 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20067] AH00163: 
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 13 09:06:37.245513 2018] [core:notice] [pid 20067] AH00094: Command 
line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jul 13 09:07:01.050648 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20067] AH00171: 
Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Fri Jul 13 09:07:01.171448 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20067] AH00163: 
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal 
operations
[Fri Jul 13 09:07:01.171475 2018] [core:notice] [pid 20067] AH00094: Command 
line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

EDIT: Both .Conf files content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin (...)
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/(site)
ServerName (site)

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory "/var/www/html/(site)">
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =(site)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The SSL one:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin (...)
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/(site)
ServerName (site)

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory "/var/www/html/(site)">
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Without showing your configuration and/or logfiles, that will be tough to debug... Also you will need to define "doesn't work"more precisely: the server does not start at all? start but does not return any content ? returns unexpected content or errors like HTTP 500 or TLS handshake errors ? etc.

Comment: When I a2ensite it all the sites on the servers prompt "Server closed the connection unexpectedly", thanks for answering, I hope this will suffice.

Comment: No it does not (suffice). How are we supposed to know what is in your configuration files?

Comment: Added the configuration files, sorry!

Comment: Did you try `apachectl configtest` ? There is no SSL related directives in your `:443` VirtualHost so this is a little strange. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay answering! I tried that command and the result was `Syntax OK`. I'm trying to enable a CRM (Vtiger) on a php 5.6 version VM, I enabled it well on a php 7.0 VM but a plugin the company needed didn't work properly on php7, so they asked me to install the CRM on the 5.6 VM and then all this happened.

Answer (score 0):

```html
1. disable site like: a2dissite default-ssl.conf
2. Restart apache like: service apache2 reload
3. Now enable site like: a2ensite default-ssl.conf 5 Restart apache again    like: service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Tried that, still server stops working when I enable the ssl.